# Adding a win and loss total

Tags: python, if-statement, counter

I have to create a program for one of my classes that will follow the basic rules of the game "Craps". This involves getting two random dice rolls and checking if the total shows for a win, a loss, or a reroll until a win or loss. That part isn't the issue at hand though. Where I am stuck is introducing a win/loss counter for these rolls. If someone could please guide me on implementing this into my code, or revising the code so it is possible to do so.

```
#Imports

import random

#Variable declaration

D1 = 0
D2 = 0
DTotal = 0
WinningValues = [7,11]
LosingValues = [2,3,12]
WinTotal = 0
LoseTotal = 0

def gameloop():
    D1 = random.randint(1,6)
    D2 = random.randint(1,6)
    DTotal = D1 + D2
    print("You rolled", D1, "and", D2,"for a total of", DTotal)
    if DTotal in WinningValues:
        print("You win")
        Cont = input("Type Y to roll again, X to quit, or S to see your stats: ")
        craps(Cont)
    elif DTotal in LosingValues:
        print("You lose")
        Cont = input("Type Y to roll again, X to quit, or S to see your stats: ")
        craps(Cont)
    else:
        print("You roll again")
        craps(Cont="Y")

def showstats(WinTotal, LoseTotal):
    print("You won a total of",WinTotal,"and lost a total of",LoseTotal,"times.")

def craps(Cont):
    if Cont == "Y":
        gameloop()
    if Cont == "S":
        print("Executing")
        showstats(WinTotal, LoseTotal)
    if Cont == "X":
        quit()

#Program running
Cont = input("Would you like to play a game of craps? Type Y to play or X to quit: ")
if Cont == 'Y':
    gameloop()
elif Cont == 'X':
    quit()
```

I have tried implementing `WinTotal += 1` after `print("You win")` but it comes back with a local variable referenced before assignment error that I have tried debugging but just haven't had any luck with it, let alone understanding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some cases not added like..

1. **if someone pressed wrong key but he/she wanted to play again.**

**Code:-**

```
import random
win,lose=0,0
asking=input("Would you like to play a game of craps? Type Y to play or any other key to quit: ")
while asking=="Y":
    WinningValues = [7,11]
    LosingValues = [2,3,12]
    while True:
        D1 = random.randint(1,6)
        D2 = random.randint(1,6)
        total=D1+D2
        print("You rolled", D1, "and", D2,"for a total of", total)
        if total in WinningValues:
            print("You win")
            win+=1
            break
        elif total in LosingValues:
            print("You lose")
            lose+=1
            break
        else:
            print("You roll again")
    asking=input("Type Y to roll again, S to see your stats, or any other key to exit: ")
    if asking=="S":
        print("You won a total of",win,"and lost a total of",lose,"times.")
        asking=input("Type Y to roll again or any other key to quit: ") 
if win or lose:
    print("Your Stats are: ")
    print("Win: "+str(win))
    print("Lose: "+str(lose))
else:
    print("You have not played any game")
```

**Output:-**

**#Testcase1** When user not played any game..!

```
Would you like to play a game of craps? Type Y to play or any other key to quit: A
You have not played any game
```

**#Testcase2** User played and wanted to know stats of his/her game and when exit also see his/her stats.

```
Would you like to play a game of craps? Type Y to play or any other key to quit: Y
You rolled 4 and 3 for a total of 7
You win
Type Y to roll again, S to see your stats, or any other key to exit: Y
You rolled 5 and 5 for a total of 10
You roll again
You rolled 6 and 4 for a total of 10
You roll again
You rolled 3 and 3 for a total of 6
You roll again
You rolled 1 and 4 for a total of 5
You roll again
You rolled 5 and 3 for a total of 8
You roll again
You rolled 1 and 2 for a total of 3
You lose
Type Y to roll again, S to see your stats, or any other key to exit: Y
You rolled 2 and 6 for a total of 8
You roll again
You rolled 6 and 4 for a total of 10
You roll again
You rolled 4 and 1 for a total of 5
You roll again
You rolled 1 and 1 for a total of 2
You lose
Type Y to roll again, S to see your stats, or any other key to exit: S
You won a total of 1 and lost a total of 2 times.
Type Y to roll again or any other key to quit: A
Your Stats are: 
Win: 1
Lose: 2
```